# Why I am not getting the expected output for bellows function overloading?

Tags: c++, overloading, dynamic-memory-allocation

This is the code example of overloading of operator new and operator delete.

my expected output is:

```
Overloaded new  
The value is :10
Overloaded delete
```

But I am getting :

```
Overloaded new  
The value is :10
```

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

void *operator new(size_t n)
{
    cout<<"Overloaded new" <<endl;
    void *ptr = malloc(n);
    return ptr;
}

void operator delete(void *p)
{
    cout<<"Overloaded delete"<<endl;
    free(p);
}

int main()
{    
    int *p = new (int);
    
    *p = 10;

    cout<<"The value is :"<<*p<<endl;

    delete p;

    return 0;
}
```

**why is this happening can anyone explain?**

Comment: `void operator delete(void *p)` should be `void operator delete(void *p, size_t n)`

Comment: Do not tag C for C++ questions.

Answer (score 0):

When replacing the global operator delete, you should provide two overloads

```
void operator delete(void *p) noexcept
```

and

```
void operator delete(void *p, size_t n) noexcept
```

In some situations it's unspecified which will be used.

Source [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_delete)